# Get all default bindings for Button widget?

Tags: tkinter

Is there a way to get all default bindings for the tk.Button widget in tkinter?
Something like this (pseudo code):

```
>>> all_bindings = root.get_default_bindings(tk.Button) 
>>> print(all_bindings)
{"tk.Button": {"<<SelectAll>>" : "<Control-/>", "<<SelectNone>>" : "<Control-backslash>", "<<Pressed>>" : "<Button-1"}}
```

I think they call it in TCL "common virtual events"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all default bindings for the tk.Button widget in tkinter?

If you call `bind_class` giving it the `Button` class, it will return a tuple of bindings.

```
print(root.bind_class("Button"))
```

When I run the above I get the following:

```
('<ButtonRelease-1>', '<Button-1>', '<Leave>', '<Enter>', '<<Invoke>>', '<Key-space>')
```

If you want to see what code is bound to an event, you can pass the event along with the class:

```
print(root.bind_class("Button", "<<Invoke>>"))
```

If you do that on default bindings you're likely to get a string representing one or more tcl commands. If you do it on a custom binding, you'll get the name of an auto-generated function that calls a python function.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to print out the association with events. Like knowing the event that is called :  a.e '<Button-1>' : <<Press>>?

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong. The event is '<Button-1>' and the handler would be <<ButtonClicked>>, is there a way to print those default handlers out?

Comment: @Module_art I think you are talking about the event call. You would have to bind each to call a function and print out the event there. Here is a quick example https://ibb.co/7SbM63z

Comment: You can get the sequence that defines a virtual event with `event_info` (eg: `root.event_info("<<PrevWord>>")`.

Comment: @Module_art: `<<ButtonClicked>>` is not a "handler" for anything. If you see an event in double angle brackets it's called a virtual event. They aren't handlers, they are custom events that can be bound to functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thiis is very useful information for me. thx